# cannot escape from 'visual' mode in vim when using PUTTY

Tags: vim, putty

I know 'esc' is the shortcut to escape from 'visual' mode, but it types "^[" character instead when I press 'esc' in PUTTY somehow. Therefore, I cannot ever escape from it except that I have to turn off the putty and restart it.

Is there any options to avoid this situation??

Comment: What happens if you hit `ctrl+[`?

Comment: From visual mode pressing `:` gives `'<,'>`. I then cleared it and typed `ex` to take me to Ex mode. 

Sorry, I don't have an explanation for your case, but found a work around to get to Ex mode.

Comment: Does this only happen when trying to move from visual mode to normal mode? or also from insertion mode to normal mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminal settings are mismatched between PuTTY and the remote machine. Fiddle with the PuTTY terminal type settings and/or the TERM= variable on the remote machine until you get them to match.

More information (such as what you're connecting to, and what the value of TERM is) would be helpful if you don't get it working within a few tries.